# How to delete dynamically created DIV controls dynamically

Tags: c#, dynamic, html

I created few div's dynamically using C#. Now I want to delete few div's from displayed div's using the div's ID, which created dynamically. I tried in many ways, but didn't solution. So please me to come up with solution. I have created around 200 nodes using below code. I would like to delete using content or div id. Please suggest me the best way to solve this.

public void draw_node(int id, int top, int left, string content)
    {
        string topstr = Convert.ToString(top) + "px";
        string leftstr = Convert.ToString(left) + "px";

```
    System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl dynDiv =
    new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
    dynDiv.ID = "window" + Convert.ToString(id); // like window1, window2, window3
    dynDiv.Attributes["class"] = "component window";
    dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, topstr);
    dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, leftstr);
    dynDiv.InnerHtml = content; // some no. like 1, 2, 3, 4
    this.Controls.Add(dynDiv);

}
```

Comment: what did you have tried, and how do you want to fire (event) to delete them?

Comment: Is this ASP.NET? Show how you created the divs.

Comment: can you show some code, are you using ASP.NET or ASP.NET MVC? What does the div generation look like?

Comment: can you provide a bit more informations! Is the answer the way you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

you could use jquery ([documentation](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
      <div id="a" class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
    </div>


<script>

    $('div').remove('.hello');

    or

    $('div').remove('#a');

</script>
```

or as dynamic funktion:

```
    <script>
function removeDIVbyID(ID)
{
$('div').remove('#'+ID);
}       

    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but the above code provided by you will not work with dynamically created DIV's. I am looking for the suggestion to delete dynamically created DIV's. I have created around 200 nodes using below code:

Comment: System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl dynDiv =
        new System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl("DIV");
        dynDiv.ID = "window" + Convert.ToString(id);
        dynDiv.Attributes["class"] = "component window";
        dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, topstr);
        dynDiv.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, leftstr);
        dynDiv.InnerHtml = content;
        this.Controls.Add(dynDiv);

Comment: @user1365604 Can you provide the code that creates the divs and tell us how do you want to delete (one deleteting hyperlink) for each item)

Comment: @user1365604 please insert your code into your question. And tell us how do you want to delete them.

Comment: for example. If I created/displayed 10 dynamic divs, I should be able to delete any div from 10 div using content or div id of particular div. Hope it will help you to guide me.